# Qualified version of arithmetic types

Tags: c, language-lawyer

This seems obvious, but I could not understand if we can treat qualified  version of arithmetic type as an arithmetic type. `int` - is an arithmetic type. Is `volatile const int` arithmetic? `6.2.5(p26)`:

> The qualified or unqualified versions of a type are distinct types
>   that belong to the same type category and have the same representation
>   and alignment requirements.

The definition of type category `6.2.5(p25)`:

> A type is characterized by its type category, which is either the
>   outermost derivation of a derived type (as noted above in the
>   construction of derived types), or the type itself if the type
>   consists of no derived types

So the type category is about if the type is a pointer/array/function and has nothing to do with "arithmeticness" of a type.

The definition of arithmetic types given earlier in `6.2.5(p18)`. So applying the only rules I cited and the definition given in `6.2.5(p18)` it is not possible to claim that `const volatile int` is also arithmetic.

The same representation and alignment requirements as arithmetic type does not make the type arithmetic.

The question arose when I tried to understand conforming usage of assignment operator `6.5.16.1(p1)`:

> the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified arithmetic
>   type, and the right has arithmetic type

```
const int a = 10;
//Do I really need this cast to make it arithmetic?
//Looks crazy
const int b = (int) a;
```

Comment: All the various type groups spewed over 6.2 are mildly helpful, you don't really _need_ to know the names of most groups. Why would you ever need to write code to ensure that a variable belongs to an artificial type group?

Comment: @Lundin When assigning a value to a variable of arithmetic type. As specified the right should have arithmetic type.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p18 - *Integer and floating types are collectively called arithmetic types*. So, qualified or not qualified.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was about to quote the same. That sums it up.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I looked at the definition of integer/floating types and found only list of types. They did not mention that qualified version of any of these types is also arithmetic.

Comment: @EugeneSh. From 6.2.5(p4): _There  are  five standard  signed  integer  types,  designated  assigned `char`,`short int`,`int`, `long  int`,  and `long  long  int`._ Unsigned is derived with `unsigned` keyword 6.2.6(p6). 6.2.5(p7): _The  standard  signed  integer  types  and  standard  unsigned  integer  types  are  collectively called  the standard  integer  types_. 6.2.5(p17): _The  type char,  the  signed  and  unsigned  integer  types,  and  the  enumerated  types  are collectively called integer types._ So how do you claim that qualified is also arithemtic?

Comment: @Lundin The qualification is not mentioned in the definition of the integer/floating types. The types are simply listed starting with _standard signed integer types_ as `char`, `short int`, `int`, `long int`, and `long long int`. As the Standard specifies the rest of integer types are derived from the types _without qualifiers_.

Comment: The very same wording is appearing about "scalar" types and "aggregate" types. I guess assuming that a qualified `struct` is not aggregate would be a bit silly. So yeah, the Standard might have missed some point (or we missed it when reading it) which is otherwise pretty obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I read the n1570 draft for C11 or the n1256 draft for C99, the full paragraph from where you have extracted your first quotation is (emphasize mine):

> §26 Any type so far mentioned is an unqualified type. **Each unqualified type has several
>   qualified versions of its type**, corresponding to the combinations of one, two, or all
>   three of the const, volatile, and restrict qualifiers. The qualified or unqualified
>   versions of a type are distinct types that belong to the same type category and have the
>   same representation and alignment requirements. A derived type is not qualified by the
>   qualifiers (if any) of the type from which it is derived.

My understanding of the full paragraph is that despite being different types, the qualified versions of an unqualified type share all other properties. So `const int` is an arithmetic type, and an integer type.

In addition, 6.7.3 Semantics §3 say:

> The properties associated with qualified types are meaningful only for expressions that
>   are lvalues.

That means that an operation on two qualified `const int` yields a result that is an unqualified `int` because it is a rvalue.

The *qualifiers* only *modify* an unqualified type for properties related to a lvalue access. The are different types because they have different access properties and the details on those qualified properties are given in 6.7.3 Type qualifiers. They have to be different types, because pointers to qualified types, which are derived type must be different types. But this has nothing to do with qualified versions of arithmetics types not being arithmetic types.